# Android - FacebookSDK change AccountKitActivity title

Tags: android, account-kit

I using the AccountKitActivity of the facebookAccountKitSdk.
Can I change the title of the AccountKitActivity? Currently, the title is "Enter your mobile number".

I've checked and find out this method, but don't know how to do it.

```
public AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder setUIManager(UIManager uiManager)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark because I don't have Android Studio in from of me right now. But because `AccountKitActivity` extends the `AppCompatActivity`, I'm guessing you would set the title in the same way?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_fancy_layout);
    setTitle(R.string.my_fancy_layout_title); 
}
```

Or if you're using tool bars...

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.your_title)
```

Comment: Because AccountKitActivity is declared as final class, so we can inherit from AccountKitActivity to edit title.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm trying to make sense your comment. You **CAN'T** inherit from a final class but you still have access to its base class's `public` AND `protected` members. Its base class is `AppCompatActivity` so you should have access to the `setTitle` and `findViewById` methods